# Magento 2.3.2: Minify and merge are not working in Production mode

Tags: magento2.3.2, merge-css, minify, production

I am using Magento 2.3.2 When I enabled production mode with Minify and Merge options for both CSS and JS only Minify is working. Js and CSS files are not merged. Did anyone came across the issue.

I have checked the Database and ran all commands. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this command and if you face any issue please resolve and try to re-run this command.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Make sure backend change has been done from your side.

May be this will help you.

Comment: I have ran this command and backend changes were done before running this command, Merge is not working.

Comment: Issue was permission was not there for _cache directory after giving permission solved the issue.